# Plist file to convert xml file in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, plist

Is it possible to convert xml file from plist, How to convert this?

Comment: A plist is already XML.  Why would you need to convert it?

Comment: Because, now i am working in android application, so that xml file want it

Comment: Nope.  It's XML already, but it's the wrong kind of XML for what you're thinking of.  It's a proprietary Apple format.  Sorry mate.

Comment: ok, then save it onexml file inside the iphone app is it possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plist is an XML formatted file. You can store the data from plist to a dictionary using the following method :-) Then you can get the values using proper key values!!

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"example.plist"];

NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format; 

NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = (NSMutableDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
```

// In case you want to save it

```
[tempDict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES]
```

Comment: but what if the XML file contains attributes in tags? Is it possible to map those in the result .plist file?

Comment: Just another pair of key-value. It should be possible

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to load the plist file to an NSDictionary, this way:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"plist"];;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath]; //or use dictionaryWithContentsOfURL to get from the web
```

Then just convert it to NSData

```
NSData *xmlData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:dictionary format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0   errorDescription:nil];
NSString *xmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add new file (plist)

Open it in source code format

copy paste xml code it will work if your code is correct

Answer (score 0):

We actually wrote a simple parser class based on NSXMLParser, walked the data using the methods present in NSXMLParserDelegate and returned a dictionary.

Then this dictionary can be saved out as a file, which will be a pList.

This results in a direct XML -> pList data conversion where the pList is an exact representation of the XML.

I don't know why Xcode doesn't have this exact thing as an example file since it seems like such a common need.

If NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML replaces all that, then I'm going to be taking another look at our code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

Open plist file in xcode.
Make a duplicate of plist file. Now you will have a prompt window. Choose **Property List XML** from **Format** Drop Down.
Add *.xml* as extension.

and Enjoy :-D